# Given numerical target variable, should I transform the target variable to obtain indicator matrix for multiclass classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a multiclass classification problem using `RandomForestClassifier`. The target variable `Y` only contain one of 3 values {-1,0,1 }. I understand that numerical encoding is necessary.

However, I would like to understand if it is necessary for me to transform `Y` to obtain an indicator matrix like below by doing `pd.get_dummies(Y)` and then feed this indicator  matrix into the `RandomForestClassifier`?

```
      -1.0   0.0   1.0
0        0     0     1
1        1     0     0
2        0     0     1
3        1     0     0
4        1     0     0
   ...   ...   ...
6516     1     0     0
6517     0     0     1
6518     0     0     1
6519     0     0     1
6520     1     0     0
```

Comparing above to feeding the untransformed target variable `Y` (i.e. a 1 dimensional series) into `RandomForestClassifier`, how would this affect the machine learning algorithm ?  Would the results be different and why ?

Is the `RandomForestClassifier` doing different things under these 2 different scenarios ?
Which approach is recommended (indicator matrix vs untransformed)?

Comment: Here you do classification, and y values are considered class labels. There is no need to encode the target values here. Target y has only to be a 1D vector. Only the features may need to be encoded if they are non numerical features. Numerical features need scaling. You can look the doc and examples here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-classifier-comparison-py

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I notice in this example, they would produce an indicator matrix https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any reason to prefer one over the other. The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit) states that you can pass an array-like of shape `(n_samples,)` or `(n_samples, n_outputs)` as `y` to `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit()`.

The only difference would be how `.predict()` returns the predicted classes. I recommend you decide the shape of `Y` based on the format that you need the predictions to be in.

Aside from that, the splitting process of each estimator is the exact same.

Comment: Which doc ? The doc here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html states that fit(X, y[, sample_weight]), so both X and y are necessary to train RFC. y is needed to train a classifier.

Comment: I added a link to the documentation. Of course both `X` and `y` are needed. I think the user's question is in regard to the shape of `y`. They don't know whether `y` should be passed as a 1D array or an array with multiple "columns".

Comment: ok thanks, I got it : "y array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)"